# Topics for an undergraduate exposition in number theory

Tags: number-theory

I have to give a 90~ minute exposition as a final assignment for my undergraduate number theory course and I'm looking for ideas on what to talk about.

I've taken abstract algebra and complex analysis courses so it'd be great to use some machinery to prove a nice result. I was thinking something along the lines of the Gelfond-Schneider theorem but its proof is somewhat dry.

Any ideas?

Comment: The prime number theorem.

Comment: Fermat's claims on what primes can be written in the form $x^2+2y^2$ or $x^2+3y^2$ (and subsequent work).

Comment: The continued fraction of $\sqrt n$, the parity of its period.

Comment: You could justify the RSA cryptosystem, assuming that hasn't already been covered in class.  If it has been covered, maybe elliptic curve cryptography would be fun?  You have plenty of rich examples there.  I did a similar presentation where I divided my audience into teams, each of which had just enough information to decrypt a secret, and then they raced.  Just make it fun.

Comment: If you decide to heed Andres' comment-- which I think is a most marvelous idea-- Cox's primes of the form x^2+ny^2 is a most excellent, accessible read.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can get a great exposition out of the general subject of continued fractions. It is ideal for undergraduate number theory, fairly easy to pick up, absolutely fascinating, deep, and useful. It is not trivial.

While you can find some good writing and proofs on the subject toward the end of any undergraduate textbook on number theory, you might want to pick up a book written by C. D. Olds titled "Continued Fractions" It is an old book from the Mathematical Association of America in the New Mathematical Library, but you will find it to be a great armchair read (nearby pencil and paper being handy).

I have several ideas on such an exposition. My thesis advisor actually listend to an exposition involving this book at an AMS meeting in San Francisco 1991 as evidenced by the copy he graciously gave me with that data inscribed inside the cover. The day I finally got around to reading it, I could not put it down till I hit the end, and I have been fascinated by the subject ever since. I have no question in my mind that you could easily entertain/amaze an undergraduate (or even post graduate) audience with an exposition on continued fractions.

Comment: For some recent references on current work, see [here](http://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2011/10/10/596-continued-fractions/).

Comment: I have to second that great reference by and from Andres Caicedo. Any time I start reading something and the first theorem is titled "Lagrange's theorem" I get so excited (to excess). We are either about to count cosets or we are about to discuss the eventual periodicity of continued fractions for quadratic surds. This is very good research.

Answer (score 3):

Not well known, the 1983 result of Jean-Louis Nicolas that RH is true if and only if $$ \frac{\phi(N) e^\gamma \log \log N}{N} < 1 $$ for all primorials $N.$ Primorial means $N = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdots p_r,$ the product of the consecutive primes starting with 2. For all known $N,$ the quantity $ \frac{\phi(N) e^\gamma \log \log N}{N} < 1. $ For that matter, in all known cases, the quantity increases slightly with multiplication of $N$ by each new prime, and gets pretty close to $1;$ for $n= 2 \cdots 211$ the ratio depicted is about $0.97008.$

On the other hand, if the ratio increases forever (to the limit $1$ ) then Cramer's conjecture on prime gaps is violated.

Cute, and very easy to compose a computer output, as opposed to Robin's Criterion which became better known.

See [PLANAT](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3613)  and [NICOLAS PDF](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/petitsphi83.pdf)

Oh, or Lagrange's method for quadratic irrationals, which means the same thing as continued fractions but requires no computer accuracy and no computer memory.

SAMPLE:

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell
Input n for Pell 
1013

0  form   1 62 -52   delta  -1
1  form   -52 42 11   delta  4
2  form   11 46 -44   delta  -1
3  form   -44 42 13   delta  4
4  form   13 62 -4   delta  -15
5  form   -4 58 43   delta  1
6  form   43 28 -19   delta  -2
7  form   -19 48 23   delta  2
8  form   23 44 -23   delta  -2
9  form   -23 48 19   delta  2
10  form   19 28 -43   delta  -1
11  form   -43 58 4   delta  15
12  form   4 62 -13   delta  -4
13  form   -13 42 44   delta  1
14  form   44 46 -11   delta  -4
15  form   -11 42 52   delta  1
16  form   52 62 -1   delta  -62
17  form   -1 62 52   delta  1
18  form   52 42 -11   delta  -4
19  form   -11 46 44   delta  1
20  form   44 42 -13   delta  -4
21  form   -13 62 4   delta  15
22  form   4 58 -43   delta  -1
23  form   -43 28 19   delta  2
24  form   19 48 -23   delta  -2
25  form   -23 44 23   delta  2
26  form   23 48 -19   delta  -2
27  form   -19 28 43   delta  1
28  form   43 58 -4   delta  -15
29  form   -4 62 13   delta  4
30  form   13 42 -44   delta  -1
31  form   -44 46 11   delta  4
32  form   11 42 -52   delta  -1
33  form   -52 62 1   delta  62
34  form   1 62 -52

 disc   4052
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
-8039536270522589  -505105258804091920
-9713562669309460  -610280421767709109


 Pell automorph 
-309159979019115849  -9839838984010482980
-9713562669309460  -309159979019115849

Pell unit 
309159979019115849^2 - 1013 * 9713562669309460^2 = 1 

=========================================

Pell NEGATIVE 
393166618^2 - 1013 * 12352985^2 = -1 

=========================================

  4 PRIMITIVE 
851931^2 - 1013 * 26767^2 = 4 

=========================================

1013       1013

jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```